# tcp client sends rst after 3way handshake

Tags: tcp, handshake

When my browser(win7) accesses the xenapp server hosted remotely on windows 2008 R2(which is on a virtualbox virtual machine), tcp handshake could be completed, then my browser sent rst to the server, there is no other msg anymore...

```
 - 153  4.991612000 123.235.17.94   217.63.13.71    TCP 74  sstsys-lm > http [SYN] Seq=4246057259 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2040538 TSecr=0
 - 154  4.991986000 217.63.13.71    123.235.17.94   TCP 74  http > sstsys-lm [SYN, ACK] Seq=298571595 Ack=4246057260 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=590459 TSecr=2040538
 - 158  5.024598000 123.235.17.94   217.63.13.71    TCP 66  sstsys-lm > http [ACK] Seq=4246057260 Ack=298571596 Win=66608 Len=0 TSval=2040541 TSecr=590459
 - 159  5.025212000 123.235.17.94   217.63.13.71    TCP 60  sstsys-lm > http [RST] Seq=4246057260 Win=65536 Len=0
```

Please give me an advice about:
How does the [RST] come from and how to avoid it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is a 3way handshake, naming it three handshake is misleading and wrong.

Comment: Not a programming question: off topic.